# json response data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am having a problem with my JSON retrieved data please go through whole code

This is my MySQL table:

```
mysql> select imgurl from images where family="shoes";
+-------------------------------+
| imgurl                        |
+-------------------------------+
| images/zara/shoes/thumbnail   |
| images/hermes/shoes/thumbnail |
| images/hermes/shoes/thumbnail |
| images/hermes/shoes/thumbnail |
+-------------------------------+
```

from the above table im retrieving the image urls with this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
          $('#sliderid, .prodcls').fadeOut(4000);
              var txt = $(this).text();
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'thegamer.php',
                  data: {send_txt: txt},
                  datatype:'json',
                  success: function(data){
                         $('#pgwrapid').html(data);
                  } 
         });
     });
 });
```

This is the php code which gets request from the jQuery ajax:

```
  <?php
//Credentials
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db = "lemonx";

//Connect
$link = mysql_connect($server, $user);
//Select database
mysql_select_db($db, $link);

//Assemble query
$family = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['send_txt'], $link);
$query = "SELECT imgurl FROM images WHERE family='$family'";

//Query database
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);

//Output result, send back to ajax as var 'response'

$imgurl=array();
$i=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $imgurl[$i] = $row['imgurl'];
        //echo $imgurl[$i]; 
        $i+=1;
        }
}
echo json_encode($imgurl); 

?>
```

Now, what happens that this is output at the below jQuery selector:

```
$('#pgwrapid').html(data);
```

OUTPUT

```
["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"]
```

My problems are:

1. Why is the backslash here?
2. Is there any code to loop over the above output and extract each path and insert it into image tag like this:

   ```
      $('#pgwrapid').append("&lt;img src='"imagepath"' alt='Thumbnail'/&gt;");
   ```

Code will be useful.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the back-slashes, but as far as creating new `<img>` elements, if `data` is an array then loop through it using a `for` loop or jQuery's [generic iterator function `$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to process the elements of the array one at a time.

Comment: i checked it with alert(typeof(data)); it gives string

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Comment: have you tried using `strip_slashes($row['imgurl'])` in your while loop?

Comment: @Sathya thanx i marked the answers which helped me

Answer (score 0):

The slashes are expected escaping, and are valid per the specification at http://json.org.  Note that even by just using Firebug:

```
"images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail"
```

evaluates to:

```
"images/zara/shoes/thumbnail"
```

... so this is nothing to be concerned about.

Yes, you could loop over each element using a standard `for` loop, or the `Array.forEach` function available in newer browsers, and simply call your append function for each thumbnail returned in the result.

Comment: i checked it with alert(typeof(data)); it gives string now how to loop through that string or convert it to array

Comment: i m parsing it like this var object = $.parseJSON(data); and then printing it $('#pgwrapid').html(object.[0]); but giving error at console

Comment: `object.[0]`?  Shouldn't it just be `object[0]`??

Comment: now this error JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error] return window.JSON.parse( data );

Answer (score 0):

The `data` you are receiving back from your PHP code is a string containing the JSON -- and the PHP JSON escapes the slashes -- which is valid.

You need to decode the json text string so, something like changing

```
$('#pgwrapid').html(data);
```

to

```
var listofshoes = JSON.parse(data); // note this the data you were having in .html(data)
for (var i in listofshoes) {
   $('#pgwrapid').append( $("<p>").text(listofshoes[i]));
}
```

And you will get a list of the data appended -- not much more work to make it an clickable image, but you know what to do next :-)

Comment: my console is giving error with the parse JSON.parse: unexpected character [Break On This Error] return window.JSON.parse( data );

Comment: With a jQuery ajax call it should parse the JSON automatically, assuming it is actually valid JSON. The code in the question sets the data type to 'json'.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call has two errors:

```
- method: 'post' (instead of type: 'POST')
- dataType: 'json' (instead of datatype:'json')
```

After this, you should check the answer. And write a loop that creates the image elements where you want.